# Why variables are initialized with max value instead of zero

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

I did not work with C++ for many years, and now i wrote c++ project with test.

When i started to debug i find strange thing that variables are not initializing with zero by default. 
For example when  i watch to the my class uninitialized variable (unsigned int), i see its value 3452816845 insted of expected zeo... 
Thats cause errors in unit-tests.
I use such initializattyion:

```
TEST_METHOD(TestPlus)
        {
            Entity* entity = new Entity();
            entity->mCreateOperator(entity->Plus);
            entity->SetContactValue(1);
            entity->SetContactValue(2);
            entity->mProcessLast();
            Assert::IsTrue(entity->GetContactValue((1+2));
        }
```

---

I have default constructor for Entity class :

```
Entity::Entity(void)    {/*some internal array initialization*/}
```

I considered that when i using new keyword all class variables will be initialized with 0 by C++ runtime..

Did i miss somethisg?

Comment: you are wondering why your uninitialized variables are not initialized? :)

Comment: It is not the max value, it is just a some value found in the memory.

Comment: It is not a random value.  Clearly you are using MSVC++ in the Debug build.  3452816845 = 0xcdcdcdcd, the value used to initialize memory allocated from the heap.  It is designed to *cause* errors, your assumption that you'll get zeros was just wrong.  Your class isn't a pod.  Remove the default constructor and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data members of your class are left uninitialized specifically because you explicitly asked the compiler to leave them uninitialized. You did this by writing a default constructor that does nothing to initialize them

```
Entity::Entity(void) { /*some internal array initialization*/ }
```

If your class had no user-defined constructor, then this syntax

```
Entity* entity = new Entity();
```

would trigger so called *value-initialization* of the new object, which would indeed set all immediate scalar data members of `Entity` to zero.

However, the very moment you wrote your own default constructor `Entity::Entity()` you basically told the compiler that you want to suppress value-initialization for `Entity` class and that you want to initialize such members *manually*. So now you have to to exactly that: manually initialize all immediate scalar data members of `Entity`. Since you did not do that in your constructor, these members were left uninitialized.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the value `3452816845` (0xCDCDCDCD) is a special fill-pattern used by Microsoft's runtime to IDENTIFY uninitialized variables. The compiler does this so that you can detect when you have forgotten to initialize a variable, and this value was picked as a "good" value because it isn't a valid address and is a large number as unsigned, and a "large" negative number in the signed range, so it's typically easy to notice that something is wrong when your code uses one of these values - it's nearly always WAY outside the range you expect it to be in.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the type has a default constructor or is a static variable, it won't be initialized at all. Reading the value is thus undefined behavior.

```
int a; //namespace scope (static storage) - value-initialized (0)
void foo()
{
    int x;  
    //reading x is illegal, you can only assign to it
    static int y;
    //guaranteed to be value-initialized (0)
}
```

Comment: Also, `int x{}` should initialize it to 0.

Comment: well a have default constructor for my Entity class Entity::Entity(void)
 {
  
 }

Comment: and use new keyvord to initialize object. Isn't this enough?

Comment: @Brans did you initialize the `int` members in the constructor?

Comment: no..  i should initialize all variables manualy in constructor? it is strange why the compiler don't do this for me

Comment: @Brans: An empty constructor does default initialization, which is no-op for things like `int`, `double`

Comment: @C.R. nope, it doesn't default-initialize types with no constructors.

Comment: @Brans you have to initialize members that aren't initialized by default (such as members with constructors)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Default initialization is performed in three situations:
...
3) when a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in a constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.
(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)

Comment: @Brans the lack of initialization is an annoying feature.  It exists because sometimes (rarely) you don't actually want to initialize a value: in practice, it generates many, many bugs, and it a headache to deal with.

Comment: @C.R. that implies the base class has a constructor.